# How do I populate a div using dajax/dajax-ice?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I am teaching myself ajax and django.  I want to click on a button and populate a `div` that already exists on a page.  I see lots of [dajax](http://www.dajaxproject.com/) examples but I don't see how I can make it populate a div.  Are there any examples on this?  Any step-by-steps or experts advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd just use the $.post and $.get (or $.ajax) and include the relevant if-statements in the view. I used dajaxice in dev server, but as soon as I put it up to the production, I found that dajaxice wasn't working.

Googling for "b-list" and "django ajax" should help. Good examples of how to get started, and this way you end up understanding the actual flow better.